# Implementing request-level caching for my microservice(s)

Tags: microservices, distributed-computing

I am trying to reduce the time the application spends computing the same thing over and over again... This sounds like a caching use-case, but it may require an architectural change instead.

The situation is this: there are many callers who, independently, submit near-identical requests to my micro-service. This happens for some time (on the same order of magnitude as the time needed to service one of these requests), then they all move to a new set of near-identical requests.

I would like to try to compute each unique request only once, as much as this is feasible.

At a given time, I will get several requests to compute each of

`{A, T0}`, `{B, T0}`, `{C, T0}`, `{A, B, T0}`, `{B, C, T0}`, etc.

Then, my callers switch to `{A, T1}`, `{B, T1}`, etc.

While I am computing the result for the `{A, T0}` request on one node, the cluster will receive several other requests for the same `{A, T0}` request. Even after I finish computing the result, but before the callers move to T1, I will still receive `{A, T0}` requests.

Also, a `{A, B, T0}` request can be broken down into a `{A, T0}` and `{B, T0}` request plus a simple join.

After an individual request is computed, it should be fairly easy to cache that result and serve it to subsequent requests. It's just that most of the duplicate requests come in while the first request is being computed...

Is there any form of request-level caching that can alleviate this situation?

It does sound a bit like trying to make POSTs idempotent, which might not be doable.

The set of possible "letters", the `A`, `B` and `C`'s above is known, but large. The subset of "letters" that do form the requests can change slightly (e.g. there could be a `{A, C, D, T2}` request at some point).

Is there a better architectural approach to this issue?
Just throwing more hardware at it would work but seems wasteful.

EDIT:

One approach that I'm considering is this:

- "like" requests get routed to the same node. E.g. all `{A, T0}` requests go to node 12
- locally, on each node I have a (LRU) cache of `Request` to `Future<Response>`
- any request either listens to an existing `Future` or registers and executes a new one
- should the node go down, the "like" requests would all get assigned to another node and the request will be processed again

Where this becomes tricky is dealing with the `{A, B, T0}` kind of requests. These get split into smaller requests, each of which could be processed by different nodes.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to mention is that your question is too broad.

Anyway I hope your whole question wraps up asking answers for these 2 questions.

---

(1) Caching a response (that was computed for a particular request) and serving that response (without re-computing) over and over again for identical requests that come afterwards.

(2) Caching a computed value (which was computed to serve a particular request) and reuse that value (without computing) to serve subsequent requests which need that value as a part of its computation.

And you need to do it in a multi-node system.

Yes. There are answers for both of your questions.

---

(1) ***HTTP Caching***

So you doubt about the possibility to tackle the multi node environment. Actually HTTP caching is **only applicable** for ***intermediate*** servers(Load Balances,CDNs etc) and browsers(or mobile) **not individual nodes**.

Simply you can configure your caching requirement and serve responses back from cache(intermediate nodes) even before the requests go into an end server node. You might need to add some code to your application as well.

Apart from simple response caching, there are lots of other out of the box features as well. For caching purpose, you would need to use a cache supporting server application (like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)) for your intermediate servers(I hope in your scenario, its your load balancer). Anyway most of them support for **GET** requests by **default**. But there are 
some work around to do to support **POST** as well, depending on the product you select.

And you also need to configure HTTP cache headers as well. It's impossible to mention all the bits and pieces about HTTP caching in a SO answer. Anyway [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) is a really good read about HTTP caching published by **Google**. And there are other web resources too.

(2) ***A Cache DB***

You can compute a particular value and store inside a cache db (which is centrally accessible to all the nodes). So that you can add the cache looking up logic to your code before doing a particular computation.

There are lots of in memory caching db applications which serve your requirement.

Ex: [redis](https://redis.io/), [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/)

---

I hope this wraps up what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! One of the important challenges is that the "identical" requests come in while the first one is still being processed. Do these caching solutions address this?

Comment: @Andrei HTTP caching will not help in that case. it needs to finish processing and cache the response in intermediate servers. But the latter can if it has already stored the value in cache db.

Answer (score 1):

This may be solved using a lease mechanism.

A leasing mechanism in cache is a technique used to prevent cache stampedes, also known as the thundering herd problem, by allowing only one client or process to fetch or recalculate the data when a cache entry is missing or expired. This mechanism helps to mitigate sudden spikes in load on the underlying system that can result from multiple clients simultaneously requesting the same data.

The leasing mechanism typically involves the following steps:

1. When a client requests data from the cache and finds it missing or expired, it attempts to acquire a "lease" for that cache entry.
2. If the lease is available, the client acquires the lease, indicating that it is responsible for fetching or recalculating the missing data. The lease typically has a short expiration time to ensure that it doesn't block other clients indefinitely if the lease holder fails to complete the task.
3. Once the client with the lease has fetched or recalculated the data, it stores the data in the cache and releases the lease, allowing other clients to access the updated cache entry.
4. If the lease is not available (i.e., another client is already holding the lease), the requesting client can either wait for the lease to expire or return a default value or an error to the user, depending on the application's requirements.

The leasing mechanism helps to mitigate the thundering herd problem by effectively serializing access to the cache entry when it needs to be fetched or recalculated. It's also important to note that leasing mechanisms are not built-in features of most caching systems but can be implemented on top of basic caching functionality as a higher-level technique.